# How to make tile set colliders with player movement by accelerometer iOS, cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, accelerometer

I am trying to make iPhone game, using cocos2d, where you roll a ball down a given path and you cannot touch certain objects.

I did an RPG tutorial which taught me how to make the tile colliders and it works when I move the ball by using isTouchEnabled, but when I apply the same logic to accelerometer it doesn't seem to register.

THis is the touch player movement method, just so you can see how it is suppose to work.

```
     -(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    CGPoint playerPos = ball.position;
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation, playerPos);

    //move horizontal or vertical?
    if(abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y)){
        if(diff.x > 0)
        {
            playerPos.x += theMap.tileSize.width;
        }else{
            playerPos.x -= theMap.tileSize.width;
        }
    }else{
        if(diff.y > 0){
            playerPos.y += theMap.tileSize.height;   
        }else{
             playerPos.y -= theMap.tileSize.height;  
        }


    }

    //make sure the player isnt off the map
    if(playerPos.x <= (theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width) &&
       playerPos.y <= (theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height) &&
       playerPos.x >=0 &&
       playerPos.y >=0)
    {
        [self setPlayerPostion:playerPos];
    }
    [self setCenterOfScreen:ball.position];
}
```

Below is how it get the position of the ball and move it using the accelerometer

```
 -(void)updateBall:(ccTime)delta{

//ball.position = ccp(ball.position.x, ball.position.y + tiltVertical);
//ball.position = ccp(ball.position.x + tiltHorizontal, ball.position.y);


CGPoint playerPos = ball.position;

playerPos.x += tiltHorizontal;
playerPos.y += tiltVertical;

ball.position = playerPos;
//make sure the player isnt off the map
if(playerPos.x <= (theMap.mapSize.width * theMap.tileSize.width) &&
   playerPos.y <= (theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height) &&
   playerPos.x >=0 &&
   playerPos.y >=0)
{
    ball.position = playerPos;
    CCLOG(@"testing for off screen");
    [self setPlayerPostion:playerPos];
    ball.position = playerPos;
}

 ball.position = playerPos;
 [self setCenterOfScreen:ball.position];

 }

 -(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration      *)acceleration{

tiltHorizontal = (acceleration.y* (-20));
tiltVertical = (acceleration.x) * 20;


 }
```

Here are the two methods that are used for getting the tile position and seeing if the properties of tile are Collidable and true (this is set in tiled when I created my map).

```
-(void)setPlayerPostion:(CGPoint)position{
CGPoint tileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:position];

int tileGid = [stLayer tileGIDAt:tileCoord];

if(tileGid)
{
    NSDictionary *properties = [theMap propertiesForGID:tileGid];

    if(properties){
        NSString *collision = [properties valueForKey:@"Collidable"];
        if(collision && [collision compare:@"True"] ==NSOrderedSame){
            return;
        }
    }
 }
 ball.position = position;
 }

 -(CGPoint)tileCoordForPosition:(CGPoint)position{
     int x = position.x/theMap.tileSize.width;
     int y = ((theMap.mapSize.height * theMap.tileSize.height)-    position.y)/theMap.tileSize.height;
    return ccp(x,y); 
   }
```

Is there something wrong with my logic? or any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the line `self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES` in your init method.

Comment: yeah, I have that, and the ball rolls around my map, expect it doesn't detect the collidable tiles.

Comment: Have you tried adding a debugger to step through, maybe there is a problem with 'properties'?